# Definir texto de pesquisa em select no html

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho o seguinte `select`:

```
  <label>Para</label>
      <div class="input_field">
        <select class="form-control" name="Para[]" id="Para" multiple>
        <option></option>
  <?php        
     $sql = "SELECT A.Discricao FROM(SELECT Discricao FROM raddb.Grupo
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nome FROM raddb.usuarios) AS A ORDER BY A.Discricao ASC";
     $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
     echo '<option value="'.$ln['Discricao'].'">'.$ln['Discricao'].'</option>';
     }
  ?>        
</select>
```

E pretendo colocar esta este filtro de pesquisa dentro do `select` como na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionei as seguintes bibliotecas:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Adicionei à classe do select `chosen-select`

Depois no `js` coloquei:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function() {
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

Mas a caixa de texto para escrever e pesquisar não aparece, como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar esta [biblioteca](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/), você tem que acrescentar todas as dependências na página: a lib do chosen (js e css) e jquery.

No teu elemento select, colocar a classe da lib que está sendo chamada: `chosen-select`.

Veja como seria na HTML:

```
<label for="id_para">Para</label>
      <div class="input_field">
        <select tabindex="1" data-placeholder="Selecione a descrição..." class="form-control chosen-select" name="Para[]" id="id_para" multiple>
  <?php        
     $sql = "SELECT A.Discricao FROM(SELECT Discricao FROM raddb.Grupo
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nome FROM raddb.usuarios) AS A ORDER BY A.Discricao ASC";
     $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
     echo '<option value="'.$ln['Discricao'].'">'.$ln['Discricao'].'</option>';
     }
  ?>        
</select>
 </div>
```

Acrescente o código da lib:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({no_results_text: "Oops, nada foi selecionado!"}); 
});
</script>
```

Veja como será a saída na HTML através desse [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/63nfmetk/).

Comment: a libs são estas `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/css/chosen.css">`, `<script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/js/chosen.jquery.js"></script>`, `<script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>`, `<script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/js/chosen.proto.js"></script>`, `<script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/js/chosen.proto.min.js"></script>`, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/sparkling/assets/css/chosen.min.css">`

Comment: faz a pesquisa mas não cria o input como no seu exemplo.

Comment: Você leu toda a resposta? `class="form-control chosen-select"`

Answer (score 0):

Bom, pelo o que eu vi você pode usar uma solução chamada select2.

inclua o seguinte stylesheet no HEAD do seu html:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.10/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

No caso do seu html coloque o seguinte:

```
  <label for="id_para">Para</label>
      <div class="input_field">
        <select class="form-control" name="Para[]" id="id_para" multiple>
        <option></option>
  <?php        
     $sql = "SELECT A.Discricao FROM(SELECT Discricao FROM raddb.Grupo
            UNION ALL
            SELECT nome FROM raddb.usuarios) AS A ORDER BY A.Discricao ASC";
     $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
     echo '<option value="'.$ln['Discricao'].'">'.$ln['Discricao'].'</option>';
     }
  ?>        
</select>
```

Note que o id do select é "id_para". Agora basta adicionar um script JS chamando a função do select2 para o id fornecido:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Select2
    $('#id_para').select2()
  });
```

Agora ao clicar na barra, vai aparecer a opção de filtrar ao digitar, junto com as opções disponíveis.

Comment: continua sem aparecer o input para escrever e pesquisar

Comment: Tente aplicar o select2 sobre a classe do select então, ficando assim:
                       
$('.form-control').select2();

Comment: não está a dar, penso que é por ter o multiple